# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

*I am new bee in d3.js and trying to draw a line chart using json file but i got an error please some one help me.where i made mistake.

Actually i tried different file format like .csv and .tsv but still got same error...

#### Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

#### Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
 body {font: 10px sans-serif;}
 .axis path,
 .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
.x.axis path {display: none;}
.line {fill: none;
       stroke: steelblue;
       stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script>
var arrData = [
   {
    "Engine": "L0",
    "date": "01-Aug-13",
    "value": 37.92625
},
{
    "Engine": "L0",
    "date": "02-Aug-13",
    "value": 39.19708333
},
{
    "Engine": "L1",
    "date": "01-Aug-13",
    "value": 44.13875
},
{
    "Engine": "L1",
    "date": "02-Aug-13",
    "value": 43.15
},
{
    "Engine": "L2",
    "date": "01-Aug-13",
    "value": 34.765
}];
 
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format.utc("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width])

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

 var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 var data = arrData.map(function(d) {
  return {
    Engine:d[0],
     date: parseDate(d[1]),
     value: d[2]
  };
  
 });
 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
 y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }));
 
 svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(xAxis);
  
 svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
 .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Price ($)");

   svg.append("path")
   .datum(data)
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", line);
   
  </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this bit of script...

```
var data = arrData.map(function(d) {
    return {
        Engine:d[0],
        date: parseDate(d[1]),
        value: d[2]
    };
});
```

to

```
var data = arrData.map(function(d) {
    return {
        Engine: d["Engine"],
        date: parseDate(d["date"]),
        value: d["value"]
    };
});
```

You were trying to get the values by index when they are actually properties, so they were previously returning `undefined`.

It was actually `parseDate()` that was returning the error message.  Passing in the correct value fixes it.

**[Here's a fixed and working example...](http://jsbin.com/oZEruJe/1/)**

Comment: please check my problem this is also something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635193/how-to-resolve-an-error-like-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefi?noredirect=1#comment64654995_38635193