# How to resolve an error like: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in angular nvd3 discrete bar chart?

Tags: angularjs, angular-nvd3

I am using angular nvd3 discrete bar chart, i am fetching values from $http and showing in the discrete bar chart, chart showing my value properly but i am getting an error like **TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**
how can i resolve this error?

> below is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);
            angular.module('plunker').controller('discreteBarChartCtrl', function($scope,$http){
                $scope.myjson=[];
                $http({
                        method : "GET",
                        url : "http://localhost/slim/myjs.php/getjson",
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                        $scope.myjson=response.data;
                        //console.log($scope.myjson);
                        },function myError(response) {
                        $scope.myjson=response.statusText;
                });
                $scope.options = {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'discreteBarChart',
                        height: 450,
                        margin : {
                            top: 20,
                            right: 20,
                            bottom: 50,
                            left: 55
                        },
                        width:600,
                        yDomain:[0,200],
                        x: function(d){return d.day;},
                        y: function(d){return d.second;},
                        showValues: true,
                        valueFormat: function(d){
                            return d3.format(',f')(Math.abs(d));
                        },
                        duration: 500,
                        xAxis: {
                            axisLabel: 'Days'

                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                            axisLabelDistance:10,
                            tickFormat: function(d){
                                return d3.format(',f')(Math.abs(d));
                            },
                            valueFormat: function(d){
                                return d3.format(',f')(Math.abs(d));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                };

            });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="discreteBarChartCtrl">
    <nvd3 options="options" data="[{ key: 'Cumulative Return', values: myjson.mydata }]">

    </nvd3>    
  </body>

</html>
```

> my $http json response is like:

```
{"mydata":[{"day":1,"second":14},{"day":2,"second":5},{"day":3,"second":85},{"day":4,"second":15},{"day":5,"second":50},{"day":6,"second":35},{"day":7,"second":55},{"day":8,"second":39},{"day":9,"second":105},{"day":10,"second":115},{"day":11,"second":55},{"day":12,"second":25}]}
```

Comment: try changing <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3> to <nvd3 options="options" data="data.mydata"></nvd3>

Comment: If still doesn't work try data="[{ key: 'Cumulative Return', values: data.mydata }]"

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: this error i am facing now

Comment: try changing application/x-www-form-urlencoded in $http to application/json

Comment: this application/x-www-form-urlencoded should be changed in what ?

Comment: in your angular controllers $http

Comment: still same problem

Comment: not sure whats wrong with your code. I recommend you to refer http://plnkr.co/edit/6t5bky?p=preview

Comment: ok thanks @Shubham

Comment: Something in one of the included scripts is expecting an object with a `.length` property , but what it's getting does not have one.  Since there's nothing in the above script that relates to that property it's difficult to help.  Try commenting things out and then putting them back in 1-by-1, so you can narrow down exactly what function call is triggering the error.  Once you've figured that out then you'll need to check the documentation for that specific function and see where you're going wrong.

Comment: ok @ Archer i am trying thanks